# Multithreaded app debug issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a multithreaded .Net App developed in Mono (Xamarin) with a lot of background async-running `Tasks`

```
public Task UpdateAsync()
{
    return Task.Run (() => {
        .....
    });
}
```

My issue is that one of the Task fails at some random point and crashes and closes the application without any error and no breakpoint triggers. I haven't been able to pinpoint the issue and its really hard since there alot of running async `Tasks`.

Is there a way to find what **Method and line** the issue is or even better break at that point?

EDIT:
i also tried registering `UnhandledException` as suggested below , but it still not handling any errors, the app just closes without any trace

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (o, e) =>{ Debugger.Break(); }
```

EDIT2:
i finally found the issue thanks to all the help here. Is it possible to suggest a way to prevent this (make the debugger break , not app crash) by altering the code below?

```
    public Task StagedUpdateAsync() 
    {

        return Task.Run (() => {
             .
             .
             .
           InvokeOnMainThread (() => 
              {
                   // somehow here it was trying to use a null object
                   // and application crashed
              });
         });
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I want to note that the Tasks themselves do not raise the exceptions from their inner code until they are directly being asked for a [`Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) property or [`Wait*` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx) or any other blocking methods, so the perfect place to search the exception is the resulting part of your code.

MSDN has a perfect article regarding the [exception handling for the Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx), you should go through it to select your own way to handle exception. I'll reproduce the main ideas from article here, but you suggest you to read the whole article:

1. `try/catch` block, easiest for the writing, but if you have a lot of tasks, it can be challenging to select a place for it in your code. Note that you should catch the [`AggregateException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) as a wrapper for inner exception, like this:

   ```
   var task1 = Task.Run( () => { throw new CustomException("This exception is expected!"); } );

   try
   {
       task1.Wait();
   }
   catch (AggregateException ae)
   {
       // foreach here
   }
   ```
2. Wait for the task to complete and examine it's state:

   ```
   var task1 = Task.Run( () => { throw new CustomException("This exception is expected!"); } );

   while(! task1.IsCompleted) {}
   if (task1.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
   {
       // foreach here
   }
   ```
3. If your code is creating some inner tasks (either [attached or not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx)), or you are creating an array of tasks, they can also raise the exceptions, and you should examine the flatten version of the [`AggregateException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx):

   ```
   try {
       task1.Wait();
   }
   catch (AggregateException ae) {
       throw ae.Flatten();
   }

   try {
       Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
   }
   catch (AggregateException ae) {
       throw ae.Flatten();
   }
   ```
4. Use the [tasks continuation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx) for filtering the faulted ones (note that the exception is still an [`AggregateException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) one:

   ```
   var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
                          { throw new CustomException("task1 faulted.");
   }).ContinueWith(t => { Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",
       t.Exception.InnerException.GetType().Name,
       t.Exception.InnerException.Message);
   }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
   ```
5. If you're still missing the exception, use the [`UnobservedTaskException` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx) for the [`TaskScheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) you are using, similar to one you're trying to handle in `AppDomain` (event args is an [`UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.unobservedtaskexceptioneventargs.aspx)):

   ```
   TaskScheduler.Default.UnobservedTaskException += (o, e) => {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());
       Debugger.Break();
   }
   // or
   TaskScheduler.Current.UnobservedTaskException += (o, e) => {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.ToString());
       Debugger.Break();
   }
   ```

Comment: This is very detailed and explained alot about Task for me. Thank you VMAtm

Comment: If the UnobservedTaskException doesn't trigger then its safe to say that the issue is somewhere else? Im suspecting either memory leak or crash in a native library call?

Comment: @iamIcarus Yes, I think the issue isn't related to the `Tasks`. May be it is a `OutOfMemoryException`, and then you have to redesign your app as there is no chance to code to execute in case of such exception.

Comment: i have updated the original question with the code where i finally found the issue. Is it possible to suggest a way to prevent this by altering the code i have quoted?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding this:-

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (o,e) =>{ Debugger.Break();}
```

And then examine e to see what the exception is, you should be able to open the threads window and switch to the thread thats causing the issue and then step back using the call stack.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , just tried it and i really hoped it would work but i still get the crash without any breakpoint hit. The app just closes

Answer (score 1):

For me this sounds very much like an `async void` issue. Read up on it [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/), it basically says:

> In short, exceptions thrown when calling an async void method isn't handled the same way as awaiting a Task and will crash the process. Not a great experience.

Especially not a great experience since you won't be able to catch it in the debugger. Probably the problem you're experiencing right now. So I'd suggest you to go hunt your `async void` methods down. Now the problem is that `async void` methods can be obvious to spot

```
public async void Foo()
{
   await Task.Run(() => {});
}
```

or well hidden behind a lambda

```
Action foo = async () => await Task.Run(() => {});
```

so it becomes a pretty tedious task to flag them down in a larger codebase. Fortunately the author of the before mentioned [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/) provides an automized solution to search for `async void` signatures based on reflection. Go check it out.

If you're using Visual Studio 2015 you also might use a code analyzer based on Roslyn. There's one especially for async/await available on [GitHub](https://github.com/olohmann/AsyncAwaitAnalyzer).

Both approaches also work well in order to avoid the problem in the future by regulary checking the codebase for `async void` signatures.
Good luck!

Comment: That is actually abit of hope for me! Thank you , will definitely read the article and try it.

Comment: i have updated the original question with the code where i finally found the issue. Is it possible to suggest a way to prevent this by altering the code i have quoted?